# Use ngAnimate with Angular-Formly (ngHide/ngShow)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate, angular-formly

I am attempting to use ngAnimate to smooth the hide/show transitions on a formly generated page. However, it does not appear that the ng-animate hooks are adding the add/remove css classes to the element. The element still hides and shows as expected but does not fade in or out like the non-formly example [Non-Formly JSBin](https://jsbin.com/xizawoquci/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Here is the sample with formly [Formly JSBin](http://jsbin.com/xexule/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

If anyone has run into this or has any ideas on how to get it working as expected it would be much appreciated.

The formly bin has been updated to reflect the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few problems. First, your jsbin using formly wasn't adding `ngAnimate` as a dependency. Also, angular-formly uses `ng-hide` to show/hide fields, not `ng-show`. If you want to make it use `ng-show`, use the [hide-directive](http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs/formly-form#attributes) attribute [like this](https://jsbin.com/bokezu/1/edit?html,css,js,output).

Or you could just change your animation css to work with `ng-if`. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I was just coming back here to correct the ngAnimate issue and add the ng-if.